# How to refresh/update a tableview after the login view?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I've a table view which is in a navigation view in my project.
I push another view for log in process.
This view accepts password and sends it to server for verification.
If the password is correct, the server returns some data in XML.

I want to refresh the table view with this XML data.
Previously I parsed the xml first before adding the navigationController view to the window.

How can I refresh the table view after I remove my login view from its super table view?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
            [self.table1View beginUpdates];
        }

```
    - (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
               atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

        switch(type) {
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                [self.table1View insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [self.table1View deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;
        }
    }


    - (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
           atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
          newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

        UITableView *tableView = self.table1View;

        switch(type) {

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;
        }
    }
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.table1View beginUpdates];
}
```

if you have this function you can use `[self.YourTableView reloadData];`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

For refresh table view you can use

```
[table reloadData];.
```

Comment: I use the following code. But I'm getting 'tableView' undeclared error. I don't have a tableView declared. My main window loads the table view from my other nib file. Any idea? 

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 [super viewWillAppear:animated]; 
 [tableView reloadData];
}

Comment: declare your tableview in IB.i mean use IBoutlet UItableView *table; and map it and connect delegate methods to filesowner.if it is in another class Syntesis your tableview, and create an instance to that class in your current class.you can reload table.

Answer (score 0):

add all the code which you have done before adding the navigationController view to the window, into your viewWillAppear method, make a method and call it from both the place.

Comment: What do you mean by make a method and call it? What this method is supposed to do? I'm trying with viewWillAppear callback also. But after I removed the login view, the underlying navigation view's viewWillAppear method is notbeing fired. Can you elaborate more on these. Many thanks.